# How to update enterprise application in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, version

Hi we developed one enterprise application.This is enterprise application so we can not find in app store.After I release one version and if I gave another release that time both the apps are installing without any problem and old version app we have to delete manually. Now my question is there any way to update old application with out deleting it. It's like how we will get version update alerts for applications which were downloaded from App Store. Please help me to implement this feature.

Comment: if they have the same app ID, it will update. Sounds like you have been creating a new app rather than increasing its version

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin It's the Bundle identifier I think you meant.

Comment: You need the same bundle identifier. How are you distributing your apps? Most MDM solutions will simply update if the bundle ID is the same.

Answer (score 0):

All iOS device identify the app with the bundle identifier only.

For example if you try to install the same IPA twice using iTunes it will override the old app. At the same time if you have 2 different bundle identifier for the IPA's it will be installed as separate APP.

There are lots of MDM solutions available to take care of the Updates but note that you cant force update an App.